# What is the DPI of the image clicked by an iphone 4 and 3gs?

Tags: iphone

What is the DPI of the image clicked by an iphone 4 and 3gs? I am using it for tesseract-ocr and i have heard that it works best on images of 300dpi. And will the DPI decrease if I re size the image before OCR'ing it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its 96 for iphone 4 and 72 for iphone 3gs

Answer (score 0):

For iphone 4 DPI is : `326`

and for iphone 3GS DPI is : `72`

Comment: i know it is the dpi for their screens but is it also the dpi for the images they click?